# Netbeans C++ method definitions take me to declaration, not implementation

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 8.01.

Whenever I previously right-clicked a method in the code, "Navigate", "Go to Declaration/Definiton", or when I created a call graph, right clicked one of the method boxes and selected "go to function" I would be taken to where the method was implemented in the cpp file.

However, I created a new project (exact same file structure as the above project), waited-through all the automatic parsing ("find usage" etc works across my project) but when I try to jump to method implementation it just shows me the declaration in the header file.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better question on the Netbeans community forums?

Comment: Do you right-click from the `Class` pane? When I do that the NetBeans sometimes (when it really makes sense) shows me two lines: `Go to Declaration` and `All Declarations`. So I click on the second line and choose the file I want - header or implementation.